# How to access nested variable dynamically in jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible

I have ansible job, where its work is to build the configuration file dynamically based on the provided input from command line.

#### host file

```
[ABC_Production]
<ip_address>
```

#### yml file

```
- hosts: "{{cluster}}"
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: True

  vars:
   ABC_Production: {
        dataSourceUsername: bobDb

   }

  tasks:
     - name: copy test
       template: src=templates/{{cluster}}.j2 dest=/tmp/test_file owner=root group=root mode=755
```

#### ABC_Production.j2:

```
bobDBuser={{ cluster+'.dataSourceUsername'] }}
```

expected output in test_file when ansible job is run with `cluster=ABC_Production` as parameter:

```
bobDBuser=bobDb
```

actual output:

```
bobDBuser=ABC_Production.dataSourceUsername
```

How to tell the jinja that `ABC_Production` is a variable and access it?

Comment: Take a look at your template and now tell us how that is possibly meant to give you your expected output. You explicitly use the `cluster` var there so it will at least include that (and so include `ABC_Production`)

Comment: I don't want to include ABC_Production statically. It must be dynamic.

Comment: logically I tried some syntax like {{ {{ cluster }}. dataSourceUsername }}. But it didn't work. Can I get working syntax to achieve this. Also used python syntax in the template like {% set temp=cluster + '.dataSourceUsername' %} ; bobDBuser=temp. python also was able to interpolate temp as ABC_Production.dataSourceUsername.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access a variable name dynamically, you have to get a little more python-y and a little less jinja-y:

```
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: True

  vars:
   ABC_Production:
        dataSourceUsername: bobDb
   cluster: ABC_Production

  tasks:
     - debug:
        msg: "The value is {{ vars[cluster]['dataSourceUsername'] }}"
```

Comment: how can this be done. ```region: 1 dev1_ips: 1,2  {{ dev[region]_ips }}```

Comment: You could use `vars['dev{}_ips'.format(region)]`. If you have any more questions about that, you probably want to open a new question rather than continuing here in the comments.